# apache kafka vs redis as message broker in production

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, publish-subscribe, data-loss, fire-and-forget

I want to use redis as my commit and push data pipeline instead of kafka for its speed and performance which is the result of fire and forget strategy. What if i need the speed and data safety? has anyone managed to use redis without data loss?

Comment: Kafka can also use fire-and-forget. Sounds like you should do a benchmark before blindly picking one or the other. And if you do actually want persistence/replication/high-availability, then Redis shouldn't be your first choice (and maybe Kafka shouldn't either)

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the answer, i know all about cap theorem and this is not the persistence problem to solve. LinkedIn is using kafka as commit and push data pipeline i dont know wether you know about this or not but kafka keeps the copy of your data as a file and persist it for a week(configurable) this guarantees minimum loss of data. so i was wondering if redis could do the same thing but with higher performance.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. And, yes, I know about Kafka (I'm the top 3 answers of Kafka tagged questions). However, I don't know anything about Redis pub-sub functions, but as a standalone cache, it works fine for everything I've used it with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very lightweight and fast replacement for both Kafka and Redis which is nats and nats streaming. After some observation on very heavy usage of nats side by side Kafka in a large company, I come to the conclusion that it is a very suitable solution. easy to maintain, safe and fast.